# C# number format in data table

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, cultureinfo, number-formatting

I have a data table and some of the columns in this data table having values of type double.

Everything is fine up to here, but when I get the value as `0.0000005` it's displaying some 5E-9 exponential value.

I need to display same value instead of exponential.

I applied culture info like this but it couldn't help me:

```
NumberFormatInfo numberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
numberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = string.Empty;
numberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 9;
CultureInfo info = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
info.NumberFormat = numberFormat;

//data table having data
targetTable.Locale=info;
```

Can one help me out?

Thanks,

Mohan

Comment: You: _it's dispalying some 5E-9 exponential value_ How do you display your `targetTable` object? Maybe you don't need to change culture; maybe you can apply a numeric format string somewhere.

Comment: **Where** do you need to display the value? In the Visual Studio's DataTable Visualizer?

Comment: Attaching datatable to DataGrid..

Comment: @AlexFilipovici No just i need to update the data table which columns are having this exponential values to normal number format and then attach to data grid.

Comment: Please post the code where you are binding the values to the data grid.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Well I'm attaching this data table to DataGrid and this grid columns are creating at runtime so i don't have any columns in data grid to specify format for columns.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici I'm binding this data table to data grid in view model where AutoGenerateColumns=true

Comment: Maybe you can do `dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "F9"` on the entire grid, then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for [`DataTable.Locale`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.locale.aspx) doesn't say anything about setting number formats; it says:

> Gets or sets the locale information used to compare strings within the table.

So it may not do what you're expecting it to do.

If you're auto-generating columns you may need to store the values as strings in the `DataTable` instead so you can specify the formatting.  Another option is to attach to the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event to set custom column properties:

excerpt from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) :

```
private void dataGrid1_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    // Modify the header of the Name column.
    if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "Name")
        e.Column.Header = "Task";
    // Replace the DueDate column with a custom template column.
    if (e.PropertyName == "DueDate")
    {
        // Create a new template column.
        DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        templateColumn.Header = "Due Date";
        templateColumn.CellTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["dueDateCellTemplate"];
        templateColumn.CellEditingTemplate = (DataTemplate)Resources["dueDateCellEditingTemplate"];
        templateColumn.SortMemberPath = "DueDate";
        // ...
        // Replace the auto-generated column with the templateColumn.
        e.Column = templateColumn;
    }

    // Cancel AutoGeneration of all boolean columns.
    if (e.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
        e.Cancel = true;

    if (e.PropertyName == "ValueField")
    {
        (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn).Binding.StringFormat = "N5";
    }
}
```

I will say that auto-generating columns is a nice way to quickly prototype a grid but I usually end up directly configuring the columns to specify number formats, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With a Windows Forms `DataGrid`, you can use the technique described on [How to: Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s.aspx) on MSDN.

For example:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["YourColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "F9";
```

for fixed number of decimal digits after the decimal separator.

To see what `"F9"` means and what other strings are valid, read [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) and [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). Simmilar format strings exist for `DateTime`, `TimeSpan`, enum types, and so on.